# Why does Hashmap Internally use LinkedList instead of Arraylist

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Why does `Hashmap` internally use a `LinkedList` instead of an `Arraylist` when two objects are placed in the same bucket in the hash table?

Comment: Consider the cost of removal.

Comment: Removing a specific item from an AL is more complex in both time and space than from a LL. Other than that, the benefits of ALs are not used at all, like finding an item by its index

Comment: What are your other two questions?

Comment: Note that it uses a linked list, not a java.util.LinkedList. the entries simply have a pointer to the next one in the bucket. This list should generally contain only one element, or at least very few, so the traversal cost is not a problem. And accessing by index isn't useful, so an array isn't needed.

Comment: Using an ArrayList would either consume too much memory (if the array is too large), or need frequent copies to larger arrays (if the array is too small). The memory used by a linked list, OTOH, is directly proportional to the number of elements, and adding a new entry is always O(1).

Comment: More to the point, why should it use an ArrayList? What's your reason for being surprised?

Answer (score 28):

> Why does `HashMap` internally use s `LinkedList` instead of an `Arraylist`, when two objects are placed into the same bucket in the hash table?

Actually, it doesn't use either (!).

It actually uses a singly linked list implemented by chaining the hash table entries.  (By contrast, a `LinkedList` is doubly linked, and it requires a separate `Node` object for each element in the list.)

So why am I nitpicking here?  Because it is actually important ... because it means that the *normal* trade-off between `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` does not apply.

The normal trade-off is:

- `ArrayList` uses less space, but insertion and removal of a selected element is `O(N)` in the worst case.
- `LinkedList` uses more space, but insertion and removal of a selected element<sup>1</sup> is `O(1)`.

However, in the case of the private singly linked list formed by chaining together `HashMap` entry nodes, the space overhead is one reference (same as `ArrayList`), the cost of inserting a node is `O(1)` (same as `LinkedList`), and the cost of removing a *selected* node is also `O(1)` (same as `LinkedList`).

Relying solely on "big O" for this analysis is dubious, but when you look at the actual code, it is clear that what `HashMap` does beat `ArrayList` on performance for deletion and insertion, and is comparable for lookup.  (This ignores memory locality effects.)  And it also uses less memory for the chaining than either `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` was used ... considering that there are already internal entry objects to hold the key / value pairs.

But it gets even more complicated.  In Java 8, they overhauled the `HashMap` internal data structures.  In the current implementation, once a hash chain exceeds a certain length threshold, the implementation switches to using a binary tree representation if the key type implements `Comparable`.

---

<sup>1 - That is the insertion / deletion is `O(1)` if you have found the insertion / removal point.  For example, if you are using the insert and remove methods on a `LinkedList` object's `ListIterator`.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

This basically boils down to complexities of ArrayList and LinkedList.
Insertion in LinkedList (when order is not important) is O(1), just append to start.
Insertion in ArrayList (when order is not important) is O(N) ,traverse to end and there is also resizing overhead.

Removal is O(n) in LinkedList, traverse and adjust pointers.
Removal in arraylist could be O(n^2) , traverse to element and shift elements or resize the Arraylist.

Contains will be O(n) in either cases.

When using a HashMap we will expect O(1) operations for add, remove and contains. Using ArrayList we will incur higher cost for the add, remove operations in buckets

Comment: "_Removal in arraylist could be O(n^2) , traverse to element and shift elements_": This actually only makes it _O(n)_, because _O(n + n)_ = _O(2*n)_ = _O(n)_.

Comment: Also think of the memory overhead. `ArrayList` overallocates, for large hashtables with a low load factor this becomes really significant.

Comment: "Insertion in ArrayList (when order is not important) is O(N) ,traverse to end and there is also resizing overhead.": This seems to be a misunderstanding. In an array based list you usually know where the end is, so insertions (including amortised resizing) are _O(1)_ there too.

Answer (score -2):

**Short Answer** : Java uses either LinkedList or ArrayList (whichever it finds appropriate for the data).

**Long Answer**

Although sorted ArrayList looks like the obvious way to go, there are some practical benefits of using LinkedList instead.
We need to remember that LinkedList chain is used only when there is collision of keys.
But as a definition of Hash function : *Collisions should be rare*

In rare cases of collisions we have to choose between Sorted ArrayList or LinkedList.
If we compare sorted ArrayList and LinkedList there are some clear trade-offs

1. Insertion and Deletion : Sorted ArrayList takes O(n), but LinkedList takes constant O(1)
2. Retrieval : Sorted ArrayList takes O(logn) and LinkedList takes 0(n).

Now, its clear that LinkedList are better than sorted ArrayList during insertion and deletion, but they are bad while retrieval.

In there are fewer collisions, sorted ArrayList brings less value (but more over head).
But when the collisions are more frequent and the collided elements list become large(over certain threshold) Java changes the collision data structure from LinkedList to ArrayList.

Comment: Java Hashmap uses singly linklist, it does not use Arraylist. Please refer to the above mentioned explanation.